# Copy notes functionality in ax2012 r3

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I want to replicate/extent the "Copy notes" functionality from Sales Order to Purchase Order (to copy vendor notes to a purchase order). But I didn't find the code for standard functionality (I want to start debug from "Copy notes" checkbox statement from Accounts receivable parameters).

This video presents the standard functionality for Sales order:
https://organicax.com/2014/10/25/sales-note-transfer-ar-parameter/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

`\Classes\SalesLineType\insert`

[image]